# Should classes manage dynamic memory on their own?

Tags: c++, memory-management

If a class needs to allocate memory dynamically (e.g. `std::vector`), is it acceptable for the class to simply allocate and deallocate the memory internally, using operator `new` or `malloc`?

The answer isn't entirely obvious to me. The lack of a system managing the memory allocation like in garbage collected languages is obviously empowering; but on the other hand, it is precisely this lack of coordination that ends up wasting memory. For instance, it would be quite trivial to make a 'fake' allocator that just passes stack memory to an object which would, under normal circumstances, require dynamic memory, but which the programmer can assert will never need more than X amount of bytes.

Perhaps you think that this issue is irrelevant in the days of large address spaces, but it feels a bit lame to fall back on the hardware, this is C++ after all.

**EDIT**

I realize now how cryptic I was with the question... Let me explain it a bit better.

When I say 'wasting memory', I specifically mean the kind of memory-wasting that happens with heap fragmentation. Reducing heap fragmentation is the most compelling point of making a memory managing system in C++, since (as many comments have pointed out) destructors already handle the resource management side of things. When your allocations are essentially random (you don't know where your new memory is in relation to other allocated memory) and every class could potentially allocate, you run into the sort of problem that data oriented design tries to fix: poor data locality.

So the question is: would it make sense for there to be a class that does the memory management, object management, heap compaction, and maybe statistics tracking (for debugging purposes) to make the most efficient use of memory and data locality?

[In this view, every class or function that allocates memory dynamically has to get a reference to that class, somehow.]

Or is it better to let every class be able to allocate without necessarily making it *part of the interface of that class*?

Comment: I don't understand what your actual question is due to a lot of confusing extra text. If your class needs to manually manage dynamically allocated memory then it can just do that. Obviously using `std::unique_ptr` or similar makes that easier. I don't know what any of that has to do with "wasting memory" or allocators

Comment: _"...If a class needs to allocate memory dynamically (e.g. std::vector),..."_ the memory is managed for you by `std::vector` no need to use `new`.  You should avoid `malloc` completely; only use `new` and if forced to; use `std::unique_ptr` (via `std::make_unique`) but prefer to use `std::vector`.

Comment: Your question seems to imply that stack allocations use less memory, or are somehow cheaper than heap allocations. Can you explain what you're thinking there? Moving a heap allocation to the stack doesn't inherently save memory. Moving an N byte allocation to the stack means the stack is now N bytes closer to overflowing; it's not free.

Comment: "If a class needs to allocate memory dynamically" Why? What for? Can you give more background? Do you know the [CppCoreGuidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines)? They can give you useful guidance.

Comment: I'm intrigued. I can sort of understand what you're getting it, but not completely. If you can flesh out your post and help us understand your thought process this could be an interesting question.

Comment: `For instance, it would be quite trivial to make a 'fake' allocator that just passes stack memory to an object which would, under normal circumstances, require dynamic memory,` Actually people do this and cpp/std has been specifically designed to support use cases like these. Thats indeed one application where allocators come in handy. If you're interested in allocators I recommend https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nZNd5FjSquk

Comment: Regarding the edit: It highly depends on the application. E.g.: high-performance applications (such as game engines) will have their own memory management systems and allocators to deal with such fragmentation issues, but it also isn't necessary for everything to worry about this. There is no single correct answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If a class needs to allocate memory dynamically (e.g. `std::vector`), is it acceptable for the class to simply allocate and deallocate the memory internally, using operator `new` or `malloc`?

Usually, we have two kinds of classes:

- managers of resources (including dynamic memory);
- "business logic" classes.

Most of the times we [shouldn't mix the layers of resource management and domain logic](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r12-immediately-give-the-result-of-an-explicit-resource-allocation-to-a-manager-object).

So, ***if your class is a manager*** of a raw resource, it allocates/deallocates, initializes/deinitializes its ***only*** resource and does nothing else. In this case, `new` is OK and even necessary (e.g. you can't instead use `std::vector` when writing your own dynamic array, otherwise you don't need to write it at all). See [RAII](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r1-manage-resources-automatically-using-resource-handles-and-raii-resource-acquisition-is-initialization).

***If your class contains some app logic***, it is not permitted to explicitly allocate dynamic memory, open sockets etc., but it uses other RAII-classes for that. At this high level C++ provides you with something that GC languages don't: it makes RAII-owners manage files, sockets etc. - any kind of resource, not just raw bytes of heap memory, so you don't need manual Java/C#-style try-with-resources everywhere you create a not-of-raw-memory manager object - the compiler does it for you as soon as you have a RAII class for that.